# How can i set fixed shaperenderer rotation in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a triangle like this;

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
shapeRenderer.setColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
shapeRenderer.polygon(new float[] { -10, 0, 10, 0, 0, 200 });
shapeRenderer.rotate(0, 0, 1, 1);
shapeRenderer.end();
```

and I rotate 1 degree in each render. But I want to fix rotation (e.g. 45) to an angle. How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: You want your ShapeRenderer to always draw at an angle of 45 degrees to the X-Axis? Or did i missunderstand you?

Comment: Yes. But to the Z-Axis.

Comment: I did not use ShapeRenderer often, but can't you rotate it outside of the `begin(ShapeType) ... end()` block? If you can you simply have to `shapeRenderer.rotate(0, 0, 1, 45);` in the `create()` or `show()` method, to set the rotation only once. If you have to do that inside the `begin() ... end()` block you need to use an
`if(!rotated) { shapeRenderer.rotate(0, 0, 1, 45);
rotated = true;
}`

Comment: Ok. Thanks. It's working :) The last question: If I want to change the rotation how can I set the new angle?

Comment: I will post an answer. Just 1 minute (: But did you set the rotation in create/show or in render method?

Comment: Yes. I set the rotation in create method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a fixed rotation you hav to rotate the `ShapeRenderer` only once.
There are 2 possible ways i can think about:

1. call `shapeRenderer.rotate(0, 0, 1, 45);` in the constructor or in `create()` / `show()` method
   This call rotates your `ShapeRenderer` by 45° (last parameter) arround the `Z-Axis` (The 3rd parameter)
2. call `shapeRenderer.rotate(0, 0, 1, 45);` in the rendermethod, only if you did not rotate yet. So you have to keep a `boolean rotated` and only if it is `false` you call `rotate()` and set it to `true`.

To answer the question in your comment: You cannot directly set the rotation, you can only rotate (relative to the current rotation). So i would suggest to store a `float rotation`, and everytime you rotate your `ShapeRenderer` you set the new value. To set a rotation in degrees you have to rotate like:

```
shapeRenderer.rotate(0, 0, 1, newRotation - rotation);
rotation = newRotation;
```

This works only if you always rotate arround the same axis, in your case the `Z-axis`. Else you would have to store 3 rotations (x,y,z). If you rotate arround a custom axis, defined by for example (0.1, 0.3, 0.6) you would need to calculate the rotation for all axes. But i don't really know how to do that. I think some Vectormath would do that. But i don't think you need that.